# Paper airline ticket/receipt

Tags: air-travel

Will my emailed ticket/receipt be sufficient to board my domestic flight? I do not own a Smartphone. Delta has a two-hour wait time for customer service.

Comment: I'm not sure how Delta works these days (so a comment, not an answer), but you probably won't be able to board directly with that. You'll need to check-in first, either online (better – you'll then get a boarding pass you can print), or at the airport, at a desk or more probably at a kiosk. Haven't use Delta kiosks in a while, but I suppose that like most others they accept either a passport, a driver's license, a credit card, or entry of the PNR (the booking reference) + name.

Answer (score 8):

It's sufficient to check-in but not to board the plane.

Your ticket/receipt includes a reservation/booking number or PNR (six letter/numbers). Starting 24-ish hours before departure you can use that to check in either online or at a kiosk at the airport. That's when you get the actual boarding pass (print it at home or at the kiosk). You need the boarding pass and a photo-ID to get through security and on the plane.

CAVEAT: there may be additional Covid related steps you need to take depending on the details of your flight.